# Spring Integration 4.3.5 needs Java 1.7

Tags: java, spring

I am using java 1.6 with spring integration : core, file and sftp which according to the documentation is java 6 compliant. However I got the following message. Any idea?

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds

Answer (score 0):

You can check [here](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/). This class exist in version 7 but not in version 6

Spring [spring link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.5.RELEASE/reference/html/system-requirements.html#supported-java-versions) says that is compatible with java 6, so I guess it is a mistake unless you are not really using the 4.3.5 version

Comment: I can't see the package **org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound** in the 4.3.5 spring integration jar

Comment: It is in spring-integration-sftp that I have also. Should be this package that need java 7 I guess.

Comment: You are right. I was lookng into the wrong jar. However the spring class doesn't import the nio package. I would look into all imports. Maybe your dependency management system is overriding some jar with new version which do  need java7

Answer (score 0):

This class is part of the Non-Blocking IO 2 API introduced with Java7.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html#package_description

Spring integration 4.3.5 seems to be compatible with java 6 however some function might need newer java.

If you take a look at SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource it extends from AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource. In [the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/4.3.x/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/synchronizer/AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java) the constructor create a new [FileReadingMessageSource](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/4.3.x/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/FileReadingMessageSource.java) that require Java7

Comment: Right, so the documentation here for spring integration is not accurate then :http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#supported-java-versions

Comment: No you can see that some feature might need newer java version. Check my edited response.

Comment: Thanks, it definitively needs Java7